# MYSQL only INSERT query slow (takes exactly 60 sec), only for some tables

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MYSQL and there is something really weird happened and I can't figure out why.

Recently, the INSERT query to some of the table become extremely slow. Weirdly enough, the query time all around 60 secs.

The tables are all with the only 10k to 35k entries, so I think they are not that big.(But indeed they are the biggest one in the database, though.)
And the slowness is only with INSERT query, DELETE, UPDATE, SELECT are all executed with 0.000x sec.

Can some help me find out why is this happening?

UPDATE: So I turned on the general log and noticed all my INSERT queries are followed with 'DO sleep(60)'. It seems my server got hacked? 
Where can I find this malicious script inject the sleep() command after INSERT?

Comment: how can you identify this insert query time??

Answer (score 0):

If you use code to build the queries, copy the code base off the server to your machine (ideally in a VM, just in case) and search for the changes within the code.  Alternatively, you could restore the code base from source control (you use source control, right?!).

If it's store procedures you use, you'll need to change them back to a working version without the sleep.  Check previous backups to try and find out when this happened, which might help a wider investigation as to how they got in and did what they did.

You'll also need to think about the wider implications of this.  Do you store user data?  If so, then you'll need to inform them that you've had your database compromised and therefore they should assume their accounts are and change their passwords.

Finally, wipe the server.  A hacked server is no longer in your control (or that's how you should look at it).  Wipe it, reinstall everything, and put in changes to help prevent the same hack happening again.